# UTF-8 in Terminator

Tags: terminal, unicode, gnome-terminator

I use the Terminator terminal emulator, and out of pure boredom, I installed and attempted to run this program: https://github.com/thiderman/doge.

However, it requires UTF-8 encoding to work. I opened Terminator's preferences and went into the default profile's compatibility tab, and it was already set to UTF-8.

I don't use any custom profiles.

The output of `locale charmap  # UTF-8` was `ANSI_X3.4-1968`. How can I make this work properly? I did test in UXterm, and it ran fine.

I'm running Arch Linux using the GNOME 3 GUI.

The output of `locale -a` is:

```
$ locale -a
C
POSIX
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
```

It seems like I have a locale setting called "C", and I can't seem to bring UTF-8 to the top.

Comment: I can confirm that it works in `terminator`. Please post the output of `locale -a`.

Comment: Made an edit with this information.

Answer (score 4):

I still want to know why my locale settings got so weird after only enabling the en_US locales during installation, but I was able to resolve the issue by adding

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_us.UTF-8
```

to my `~/.bashrc`

Comment: The locale setting you need is `LC_CTYPE`. So make that `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`. I'm surprised that Terminator isn't doing it automatically: that should be its job.